# awt Robot.Keypress not working in full screen games

Tags: java, awt, keypress, awtrobot

`robot.keypress()` works on notepad and browsers but isn't working on full screen games.

Why would this be so?

Code:

```
robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_S);
```

Comment: There could be any number of reasons. The window that is accepting key board input isn't focused for example

Comment: but it is working for the notepad and browser even when my java frame has lost focus...i read somewhere come full screen games have some shield to prevent inputs from bot..any suggestions?

Comment: Write a native interface that injects key codes directly into the keyboard driver

Comment: i have made an android app which communicates via client server with the javaswing application which accepts the button press from the android app and the javaswing app with the help of robot awt presses the key...

Comment: It all depends on exactly what your are trying to achieve. Some game stay bypass the OS message loop and connect directly to the keyboard driver.

Comment: ok thanks..another solution i think maybe creating keyboard drivers for my app...any idea how do i create that?

Comment: well basically...i am trying to develop an android application which will communicate with the java swing application...and on if conditions the keypress should work....it is working on notepad and browser...but aint working on the games(full screen)...so any solutions? or how do i install the application as a keyboard on my pc?

Comment: Unless you can find a way to inject key strokes directly into the hardware layer (probably via JNI/JNA) I don't think you're going to have much success

Comment: ohh ok... thank you !!! any other alternative you suggest? or some keypress other than robot class?

Comment: it just needed a delay thats it