# Why is Java AWT Robot not working in game while works in other windows?

Tags: java, awt, awtrobot

I am trying to create a java program to be able to remotely control some actions in games. Anyway, I could not make the robot work in the actual game, even if anywhere else works. I tried bought keypress and mouse press. Could you please help me with this?

Is it possible that the actual game stops the Robot as a 'cheat blocker' or anything? if yes then what can I do to make it work?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

public class Main {

    private static Robot robot;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
        robot = new Robot();
        robot.delay(2000);

        while (true) {
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            robot.delay(100);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
//            keystroke(KeyEvent.VK_A);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
    }

    private static void keystroke(int key) {
        robot.keyPress(key);
        robot.delay(1000); // hold for a tenth of a second, adjustable
        robot.keyRelease(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: See the comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15346166/522444)

Comment: Many games have "anti cheat" features which prevent the use of things like robot and scripts been used to "mine" or otherwise perform repeated task